# How to make existing class serialized

Tags: c#, asp.net

Generally I use `[Serializable()]` before any class that I want to save in `ViewState`.

Suppose I have store `HtmlTableRowCollection`'s object. How can I serialize it ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by *Suppose I have store HtmlTableRowCollection's object*. Is `HtmlTableRowCollection` a custom collection object?

What if you just use the `[Serializable]` attribute? Doesn't it gets serialized properly?

If in case, you are trying to provide a custom serialization logic then you can consider implementing [`ISerializable Interface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); by implementing the `GetObjectData()` method.

```
[Serializable]
public class HtmlTableRowCollection : ISerializable
{
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
       //Provide your custom serialization logic here;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that he wants to serialize https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablerowcollection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren is right. I want `HtmlTableRowCollection` is not custom collection object. I want to store it into view state so needs  to serialize? Can I? For time being I used session for saving this but still curios to know.

Comment: @ImadoddinIbnAlauddin, In that case, I don't think you need to explicitly serialize it. It should get serialize/deserialize automatically when you store into viewstate and retrieve back.

Comment: @ImadoddinIbnAlauddin, consider accepting the answer if it helped to solve the problem at hand.